# How to get the Tumblr ProfileName from user accesstoken

Tags: ios, iphone, tumblr

I have unable to handle the Tumblr profile name after login for using ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecretKey.Here i have to want some Tumblr functionality like ,whenever i go to my IOS Application, in that i had to show all the share options like Facebook,Twitter,Email and Tumblr with using to Connect and Disconnect Buttons.While Connect to the Facebook i get the profile name and displayed into the FB Label and Twitter Label.

But here i have login into the Tumblr but i didn't get the Profile name or Blog name.

For using these code

```
- (void) signAndSendWithTokenKey:(NSString *)key andSecret:(NSString *)secret {
    [self signRequestWithClientIdentifier:tumblrConsumerKey secret:tumblrConsumerSecret tokenIdentifier:key secret:secret usingMethod:ASIOAuthHMAC_SHA1SignatureMethod2];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];    
}
```

Any Suggestions ...Thanks In Advanced

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest making an API request to `api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info` in order to get the Tumblr's Name.

EDIT: Here is a link to the appropriate Tumblr API reference: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#user-methods